# Create new column based on multiple groupby conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want a new column in this df with the following condition. The column `education` is a categorical value that goes from 1 to 5 (1 is the lower level of education and 5 is the higher level of education). I want to create a function with the following logic (so as to create a new column in the df)

First, for any id check if there is at least a education level graduated, then the new column must have the higher level of education graduated.

Second, if there is no graduated education level for some particular id (must have all educaction level in "In course"). So, must check the maximium  level of education and substract one.

```
df
id  education stage
1   2         Graduated
1   3         Graduated
1   4         In course
2   3         In course
3   2         Graduated
3   3         In course
4   2         In course
```

expected output:

```
id  education stage       new_column
1   2         Graduated   3
1   3         Graduated   3
1   4         In course   3
2   3         In course   2
3   2         Graduated   2
3   3         In course   2
4   2         In course   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'education': [2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2],
                   'stage': ['Graduated', 'Graduated', 'In course', 'In course', 'Graduated', 'In course', 'In course']})


max_gr = df[df.stage == 'Graduated'].groupby('id').education.max()
max_ic = df[df.stage == 'In course'].groupby('id').education.max()

# set all cells to the value from max_ed
df['new_col'] = df.id.map(max_gr)
# set cells that have not been filled to the value from max_ic - 1
df.loc[df.new_col.isna(), ['new_col']] = df.id.map(max_ic - 1)
```

`series.map(other_series)` returns a new series where the values from `series` have been replaced by the values from `other_series`.

Comment: Yep, easy to read. I upvoted and posted an alternative solution I think is even more readable based on yours. I put it inside your solution at first but moved it out. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @AntonvBR I agree, your solution is even easier to read. I didn't know series.update().

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
df['new'] = df.loc[df['stage'] == 'Graduated']\
              .groupby('id')['education']\
              .transform(max).astype(int)

df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(df.loc[df['stage'] == 'InCourse']\
                               .groupby('id')['education']\
                               .transform(max).sub(1)).astype(int)
```

**Result**

```
   id  education      stage  new
0   1          2  Graduated    3
1   1          3  Graduated    3
2   1          4   InCourse    3
3   2          3   InCourse    2
4   3          2  Graduated    2
5   3          3   InCourse    2
6   4          2   InCourse    1
```

**Explanation**

- First, map to "Graduated" dataset grouped by id on max education.
- Second, map to "InCourse" dataset grouped by id on max education minus 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative solution** based on Markus Löffler.

```
max_ic = df[df.stage.eq('In course')].groupby('id').education.max() - 1
max_gr = df[df.stage.eq('Graduated')].groupby('id').education.max()

# Update with max_gr
max_ic.update(max_gr)

df['new_col'] = df.id.map(max_ic)
```